# PHP array to XML with attributes in Slim framework

Tags: php

In CakePHP I know the XML-class in cake.libs. What I like on this easy to use class is the fact that you can convert an array to xml with attributes.
On a current project I'm working with Slim Framework and I am missing this nice class.

Does anybody know how I can convert an PHP-array to XML with attributes easily?

I tried this one but unfortunately its not easy to handle result arrays from database cause you have to define the attributes inside the array.

Maybe I have missed something in Slim? Or does anybody know how to adapt the CakePHP class to Slim?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [`cakephp/utility`](https://github.com/cakephp/utility) using composer in your PHP project and use the `Cake\Utility\Xml::build()` class.

```
composer require cakephp/utility
```

Comment: You can just copy / paste the content of utility/Xml.php to your project